# A presheaf can be seen as a contravariant functor

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory

> Given a topological space $(X, \mathscr{T})$ we have a category Open$(X)$ of open sets where the objects obj$($Open$(X))$ are the open sets of $X$ and the morphisms are inclusions mappings between subsets and none otherwise, i.e. if $U \subseteq V$, then $i : U \hookrightarrow V, x \mapsto i(x) = x$. Verify that the data of a presheaf is precisely the data of a contravariant functor from the category of open sets of $X$ to the category of sets Sets.

A contravariant functor $\mathscr{F}$ is a functor from the opposite category Open$^{op}(X)$ into Sets. In other words, the objects are open sets as in Open$(X)$ but the morphisms are arrow reversed, i.e. for $U \subseteq V$ we have $i^{op} : V \rightarrow U, x \mapsto i^{op}(x) = x$. Hence, the morphisms become restrictions (**am I right?**).

So now we have for each $\mathscr{F} : \text{obj}(\text{Open}(X)) \rightarrow \text{Sets}, U \mapsto \mathscr{F}(U)$. In other words, to each open set of $X$ there is a set $\mathscr{F}(U)$ (the sections of $\mathscr{F}$ over $U$).

We also have for any $U \subseteq V$ such that $\mathscr{F} : \text{Hom}(V, U) \rightarrow \text{Hom}(\mathscr{F}(V), \mathscr{F}(U)), i^{op} \rightarrow \mathscr{F}(i^{op})$. In other words, for any restriction from $V$ to $U$, we have $\mathscr{F} : \mathscr{F}(V) \rightarrow \mathscr{F}(U)$. **How does $\mathscr{F} : \mathscr{F}(V) \rightarrow \mathscr{F}(U)$ become the restriction map** res$_{V, U} : \mathscr{F}(V) \rightarrow \mathscr{F}(U)$ **as required in a presheaf?**

A functor is required to preserve identities, i.e. $\mathscr{F}(\text{id}_{U}) = \text{id}_{\mathscr{F}(U)}$. Since inclusion/restriction of $U$ to itself becomes $i(x) = x = \text{id}(x)$.

And a functor also has to preserve compositions, that is, if $U \subseteq V \subseteq W$ such that we restrict $W$ to $V$ via $i^{op}$ and we restrict $V$ to $U$ via $j^{op}$, then by composition of mappings we can restrict $W$ directly to $U$ via $i^{op} \circ j^{op}$ and by functoriality we must have $\mathscr{F}(i^{op} \circ j^{op}) = \mathscr{F}(i^{op}) \circ \mathscr{F}(j^{op})$. So if res$_{V, U} = \mathscr{F}(i^{op})$ then this fullfills the last criterion for a presheaf.

Comment: How should I correctly rephrase the title?

Comment: "A presheaf is a contravariant functor" (or "can be seen as") would be better, and not carry the implication Jesse Madnick takes issue with.